# ScrollView with Constraint Layout ( White Space at Top )

Tags: android, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I've been using ScrollView as parent and Constraint Layout as Child. The Children of Constraint layout is bound between the top and the bottom of its parent ( Let us say **View 1**).

When I add another TextView ( **View 2** ) and bounds as 50 width and wrap_content as height.Now if I add Long text value, Both **View 1** and **View 2** Starts going down and If I increase the amount text and its starts going out of the screen.

Any Solution for this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello Wosaddsadasrld!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello Wosaddsadajhsf
            iabdjkjasbdjsjabdsajbjahsbdjabshjdsajbs
            ajbjhbdsjabshbdbhjbasjhbhadjbjhabsjadbjdbs
            ajbdbashbbasdbhdbashjbjkvdsbkjvdbsjkbdsvsrld!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/line1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line3"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Bagadehs"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/line2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line4"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="sdfdsf"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/line3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line5"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="rtte"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/line4" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[Kindly see the Scroll bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU4MQ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMTTI.png)

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to do here? how would your result look like in the end?

Comment: I'm trying to show a view in the middle of the screen and its text size increase then I want the user to scroll and see the remaining. 
But as the view text size increase, it( textView) takes the scroll as Parent and determines the height then.
Currently I'm using paddingTop as Half of screen height as workaround.

Comment: Can u just share your expectation design (may be hand drawn)